# Generate possible truth values of variables in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, logic, truthtable

I have an array with variables `var variables = ['a', 'b', 'c']`.

I want to change the output to

```
[
  {
    'a': true,
    'b': true,
    'c': true
  },
  ...
]
```

What I want is to get an array of objects with all the possible truth values to these variables, which is something like http://jamie-wong.com/experiments/truthtabler/SLR1/ or https://stackoverflow.com/a/26610870/1715426.

So, for instance, when I have 3 variables (i.e. 3 elements in `variables`, I will get 2^3 = 8 combinations of truth values).

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var variables = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    var numberOfSets = 1 << variables.length;
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSets; i++) {
      results.push({});
      for (var j = 0; j < variables.length; j++) {
        if (((1 << j) & i) > 0) {
          results[i][variables[j]] = true;
        } else {
          results[i][variables[j]] = false;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(results);
```

Is this what you mean? I got

```
  [ { a: false, b: false, c: false },
    { a: true,  b: false, c: false },
    { a: false, b: true,  c: false },
    { a: true,  b: true,  c: false },
    { a: false, b: false, c: true  },
    { a: true,  b: false, c: true  },
    { a: false, b: true,  c: true  },
    { a: true,  b: true,  c: true  } ]
```

by running the code. I am using simple bit manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

if you have 3 variables, you can think of it as the permutation of 3 bits:

`000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111`

we go from 0 to `2^n` where `n` is `variables.length` converting the numbers to binary and prepending 0's if the length is less then `n`, then we map every char to a variable, converting the String `binary.charAt(index)` to Int with `+` then to Bool using `!!`.

```js
var variables = ['a', 'b', 'c']
var output = []

var n = variables.length

for (var i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) {
 var binary = i.toString(2)
 binary = "0".repeat(n - binary.length) + binary
 output.push(variables.reduce(function(obj, variable, index) {
   obj[variable] = !!+binary.charAt(index)
  return obj
 }, {}))
}

console.log(output)
```